# NS_OPTIONS has a flaw?

Tags: objective-c, c

In the objective-c variant of C, NS_OPTIONS exists to help validate bit masks. But it seems to have an inherent flaw. If I need to define a value representing a bitwise OR of all of the bits, e.g. FubarAllOptions some would say that the convention is to simply use INT_MAX. However this has a problem.

Imagine that I use NS_OPTIONS for the lower five bits of a uint8_t. e.g.

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(uint8_t) {
 FubarA=1,
 FubarB=1<<1,
 FubarC=1<<2,
 FubarD=1<<3,
 FubarE=1<<4,
 FubarAllOptions=0xff // MAX
} FubarOptions;
```

If I bitwise clear each of the assigned bits of a FubarOptions variable, the remaining three upper bits will remain set. Therefore if I check for the NS_OPTIONS value being nonzero as a test of whether all the bits are cleared, it will appear that some bits are still set. Therefore a bug. FubarAllOptions includes bits that are not assigned.

Q: How do I define FubarAllOptions so that it only includes assigned bits, without laboriously typing out all of the potential options and Or'ing them? i.e. FubarA|FubarB|.... But this would be vulnerable to typo mistakes.

Sure I can take the largest, <<1 and subtract 1. But too this would be vulnerable to typo mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set all options manually:

```
FubarAllOptions = (FubarA | FubarB | FubarC | FubarD | FubarE)
```

Of course, you can also fix the problem by always checking every option manually instead of masking them all and then comparing with zero.

You are too worried about typing mistakes when you should rather worry what will happen when you start using another bit.

Comment: "what will happen when you start using another bit." Agreed. When you add a new option, do you want everyone using `FubarAllOptions` to *always* turn that new option on? It's hard to imagine the use case of that. You should ask carefully why you even want an "all options, no matter what they mean, should be on" setting. "FLIP ALL THE SWITCHES!!!" is not generally a recommended programming pattern.

Comment: @Sulthan Not true. Typing mistakes have led to million-dollar calamities.

Comment: (I can't help but be reminded of gcc's `-Wall` which does not actually turn on all warnings.)

Comment: @RobNapier The all-bits option exists because it is used.

Comment: But does it mean "all flags, no matter what they mean, including new flags that are added in the future?" Or does it mean "the current A|B|C|D|E and we'll have to decide whether it includes new flags when they're added?" (If no new flags are ever going to be added, then avoiding a typing mistake one time is not difficult. Just review it carefully one time and move on. All the interesting questions are about future changes IMO and how easy it will be to detect mistakes *then*.)

Comment: I vote: (i) do it manually; and (ii) add `NSAssert`s in whatever piece of API you have that receives values for `!(valuePassed & ~FubarAllOptions)` i.e. that the value you've received does not contain any flags that you forgot to put into `FubarAllOptions`. To make sure you keep `FubarAllOptions` up to date.